# Ошибка памяти, библиотека Qt

Tags: c++, qt5

Следующий код создает окно и при закрытии:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    QPushButton quitButton("Exit");

    QObject::connect(&quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout layout;
    layout.addWidget(&textEdit);
    layout.addWidget(&quitButton);

    QWidget window;
    window.setLayout(&layout);

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

вызывает следующую ошибку:
`QtCalc(47351,0x7fffce3e73c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5ea469f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Оконный виджет попытался уничтожить дочерние widget-ы и макет так, будто они размещены в куче. На самом же деле всё размещено на стеке, а потому стандартная библиотека пресекла эту попытку и аварийно завершила приложение.

Данная же попытка была вызвана тем, что любой `QObject` (потомком которого является `QWidget`) обязуется прибирать за собой все дочерние объекты, освобождая от этой обязанности автора программы.

Для решения проблемы можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что любой дочерний `QObject` при своём уничтожении передаёт сигнал родителю, и тот убирает удаляемый объект из своего списка во избежание повторного удаления.

То есть будь `QTextEdit`, `QPushButton` и `QVBoxLayout` уничтожены до `QWidget`, последний не стал бы трогать уже уничтоженные объекты, и программа завершилась бы нормальным путём. Для достижения этого эффекта достаточно поместить объявление `QWidget window;` перед всем тем, что будет в него позднее добавлено:

```
// ...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget window;         // <---

    QTextEdit textEdit;

   // ...
}
```

Это сработает, потому что локальные переменные (и члены класса) всегда уничтожаются в порядке, обратном тому, в котором они создавались.